# Mechanics of an elevator bed/platform in a Tiny House

Tags: classical-mechanics, torque, building-physics

I'm building a Tiny House that will have a platform that moves about 1 meter up and down. Given that I have little to no experience using pulleys, cogwheels or any of the like, I'd like some feedback on the design I made. The driving force would be a power drill operated winch placed off axis. To tackle the problem that the pulling force is out off line with the axis the load would be moved along, I thought of using a rotating bar. All four edges of the moving platform would connect to the bar. I'm having trouble imagining how the pulling force of the winch translates to rotating the bar and also what kind of bearings should be used to mount the bar. I'm also considering using gears instead of a winch. The lack of working space is a complicating factor (close to the roof, close to the windows on both sides).

All advice is welcome: feeddback on how to improve this post, feedback on the design, usefull links and resources, tips on parts to use, how to calculate the sizes of the components relative to the forces applied, alternative ways of approaching the challenge.

[image]

[image]